# Unable to lookup remote EJB on Websphere 8

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-8

I have deployed an EJB with local and remote interfaces, and I can lookup the local one OK after deployment, but I'm not able to to do with the remote, from a Java SE client.

The EJB code is simple:

```
@Local(DemoFacade.class)
@Remote(DemoFacadeRemote.class)
@Stateless
public class DemoFacadeBean implements DemoFacade
<snip>
```

The lookup code is also simple:

```
Properties env1 = new Properties();
env1.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env1.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809");
Context initialContext;

initialContext = new InitialContext(env1);
Object ejbHome =  initialContext.lookup("cell/nodes/OVLM46008QPZKQ1Node01/servers/server1/ejb/DemoFacadeRemote");
```

I also tried many variations of the jndi lookup, but all fails with the same error.

```
Object ejbHome = initialContext.lookup("cell/nodes/OVLM46008QPZKQ1Node01/servers/server1/java:global/WebSphereDemo/WebSphereDemoEJB/DemoFacadeBean!com.test.DemoFacadeRemote");
```

I have added the following arguments to help debug:

```
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.Debug=true -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.CommTrace=true -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.Debug.Output=c:/temp/client.log -Dcom.ibm.ejs.ras.lite.traceSpecification=*=all -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/data/workspace/WebSphereDemoEJBTest/lib/websphereclient/eee
```

The classpath is set to all jars of the websphere/lib folder.

The full console output is (sorry by the length of the output, some of it is ommitted). Real error at the very end.
thanks for any suggestions.

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
<snip>

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:122 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace               >  lookUpRootContext Entry 
                                 bindingName=IIOP_DEFAULT_ROOT
                                 rootBindingData=com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.BindingsTableData@fffd6386
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:123 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace               <  lookUpRootContext Exit 
                                 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Root context not found.
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:123 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.Cache                   3   lookup 
                                 NamingException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Root context not found.
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:123 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.Cache                   <  lookup Exit 
                                 Throwing CacheEntryNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.CacheEntryNotFoundException: Entry "IIOP_DEFAULT_ROOT" not found in cache. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Root context not found.]
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:123 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         >  getRootJndiContext Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:124 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           3   SOURCE CODE INFO: SERV1/ws/code/naming.client/src/com/ibm/ws/naming/util/TransactionUtil.java, WAS.naming.client, WAS80.SERV1, m1116.12, ver. 1.5
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:124 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           >  suspend Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:127 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerFactory                 >  getUOWManager Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:128 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerFactory                 <  getUOWManager Exit 
                                 com.ibm.ws.uow.ClientUOWManagerImpl@fffdb786
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:128 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           3   suspend 
                                 current transaction suspended
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:128 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           <  suspend Exit
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:129 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         >  getRootContextFromServer Entry 
                                 wsnObjectUrl=corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/WsnNameService
                                 objectUrl=corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/NameService
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:129 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         >  getWsnNameService Entry 
                                 objectUrl=corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/WsnNameService
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:130 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         3   getWsnNameService 
                                 Attempting to connect to name server using URL corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/WsnNameService
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:130 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         >  stringToObject Entry 
                                 string=corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/WsnNameService
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:137 EST] 00000000 er.router.selection.WLMClientForCommonRouterImpl >  initialize Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:138 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   version :  
                                 1.30 
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:138 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              >  getWLMIOR Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:138 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - typeid= 
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:138 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - host= ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:138 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - port= 2809
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:139 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - objectKey= 0x57736e4e616d6553657276696365
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:139 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - taggedcomponent= [Lcom.ibm.rmi.Profile$TaggedComponent;@fffde943
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:143 EST] 00000000 ebsphere.cluster.topography.KeyRepositoryFactory 3   version :  
                                 1.2 
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:147 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.cluster.topography.KeyRepositoryImpl  3   version :  
                                 1.15 
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:147 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   component_data
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:147 EST] 00000000 er.router.selection.WLMClientForCommonRouterImpl <  initialize - getWLMIOR returned a null Exit
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:192 EST] 00000000 er.router.selection.WLMClientForCommonRouterImpl >  initialize Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:192 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              >  getWLMIOR Entry
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:192 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - typeid= IDL:com.ibm/WsnBootstrap/WsnNameService:1.0
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:192 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - host= OVLM46008QPZKQ1.oakton.com.au
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:192 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - port= 0
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:193 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - objectKey= 0x4a4d4249000000104773e3aa0000000000000000000000000000000000000024000000080000000000000000
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:193 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   getWLMIOR - taggedcomponent= [Lcom.ibm.rmi.Profile$TaggedComponent;@fffc731f
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:193 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.wlm.configuration.WLMIOR              3   component_data
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:193 EST] 00000000 er.router.selection.WLMClientForCommonRouterImpl <  initialize - getWLMIOR returned a null Exit
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:198 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         <  stringToObject Exit 

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:200 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         <  getWsnNameService Exit 

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:202 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         >  mergeWsnNSProperties Entry 

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:217 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter                       3   FFDC exception: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine:host=OVLM46008QPZKQ1.oakton.com.au,port=0  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E02  completed: No com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection 448
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:237 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.RasUtil                   3   SOURCE CODE INFO: SERV1/ws/code/naming/src/com/ibm/ws/naming/util/RasUtil.java, WAS.naming, WAS80.SERV1, m1116.12, ver. 1.2
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:238 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter                       3   FFDC exception: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties 1549
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:238 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory           mergeWsnNSProperties 
                                 FFDC: sourceId=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties, probeId=1549
                                 org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1884)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1547)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:431)
    at com.oakton.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:295)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    ... 17 more

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:239 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         <  mergeWsnNSProperties Exit 
                                 javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1550)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:431)
    at com.oakton.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1884)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1547)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:295)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    ... 17 more

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:240 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter                       3   FFDC exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No] com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext 963
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:240 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory           getRootJndiContext 
                                 FFDC: sourceId=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext, probeId=963
                                 javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1550)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:431)
    at com.oakton.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1884)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1547)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:295)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    ... 17 more

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:242 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory         3   getRootJndiContext 
                                 Could not connect to name server using URL corbaloc:iiop:1.0@ovlm46008qpzkq1.oakton.com.au:2809/NameService
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:245 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter                       3   FFDC exception: javax.naming.NamingException: NMSV0602E: Naming Service unavailable. A communications error occurred. [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]] com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext 886
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:247 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory           getRootJndiContext 
                                 FFDC: sourceId=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext, probeId=886
                                 javax.naming.NamingException: NMSV0602E: Naming Service unavailable. A communications error occurred. [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:431)
    at com.oakton.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1550)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:960)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1884)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1547)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:295)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    ... 17 more

[26/07/2011 15:49:32:247 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           >  resume Entry 
                                 wrapper=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil$TransactionWrapper@fffae2a9[_manager=com.ibm.ws.uow.ClientUOWManagerImpl@fffdb786, _token=null]
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:248 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           3   resume 
                                 no transaction to resume
[26/07/2011 15:49:32:248 EST] 00000000 com.ibm.ws.naming.util.TransactionUtil           <  resume Exit
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1550)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:431)
    at com.oakton.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:20)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1884)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1264)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1547)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:295)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:436)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:89)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1981)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2006)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Is the server running on localhost:2809?  What port is shown in the NMSV0018I message in SystemOut.log?  Does a simple Socket.connect work? new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 2809))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came across something like this and adding these two params helped:

-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:$profile_root/properties/ssl.client.props

-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:$profile_root/properties/sas.client.props

You may also have to set these params too or hardcode them in sas.client.props, I noticed that the prompt kept timing out waiting for login credentials if I did not include these ones.

-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginUserid=${WasUserid}

-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginPassword=${WasPassword}

-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginSource=properties

just noticed that my listener address / url format is different too:
-Djava.naming.provider.url=iiop://localhost:${ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS} . You can find the orb  listener port in config/cells//nodes//serverindex.xml .

Hope that works!

Comment: I found out that Websphere is by default SSL protected, so easiest way is to use SSL, as per comments.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Banged my head against wall for a week to find this stupid Webpshere setting. Also helped by this post http://mresetar.blogspot.com/2012_06_01_archive.html

Comment: to be precise, WebSphere 8+ has RMI/IIOP security set to SSL_required by default. Prior to that (WAS7 and below), it was SSL_supported out of the box.

Comment: I wonder why it only works if I set the file references as a system var ```com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL```. It doesn't work in the ```javax.naming.InitialContext ```